# Get last purchase price from a pandas dataframe according the order date

Tags: pandas

**# This is my purchase dataframe**

```
data = {
    'order_date': ['2022-01-02' , '2022-05-03' , '2022-02-01' , '2022-09-30'],
    'order_id' : ['001' , '002' , '003' , '004'],
    'item_code': ['12-05', '13-05', '13-05' , '12-05' ], 
    'price': [20, 21, 19,17], }

df_purchase = pd.DataFrame (data)

df_purchase
     order_date    order_id   item_code    price
     2022-01-02    001        12-05        20
     2022-05-03    002        13-05        21
     2022-02-01    003        13-05        19
     2022-09-30    004        12-05        17
```

**I have wanted to get the last purchase price of the item according the order_date like below**

```
     order_date    order_id   item_code    price
     2022-05-03    002        13-05        21
     2022-09-30    004        12-05        17
```

I have tried in many ways but couldn't achieve the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(
    df_purchase
    .sort_values(['item_code', 'order_date'])
    .groupby('item_code', as_index=False)
    .last()
)
```

```
  item_code  order_date order_id  price
0     12-05  2022-09-30      004     17
1     13-05  2022-05-03      002     21
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be as follows:

- First, use [`df.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) to sort the df on `order_date`.
- Next, use [`df.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) on column `item_code`, setting the `keep` parameter to `last`.
- Finally, reset the index using [`df.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).

```
res = df_purchase.sort_values('order_date').drop_duplicates(
    subset='item_code', keep='last').reset_index(drop=True)

print(res)

   order_date order_id item_code  price
0  2022-05-03      002     13-05     21
1  2022-09-30      004     12-05     17
```

Alternative method could be:

- First, turn your `order_date` values into "datetime", using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html). Doing so allows you to use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) without having to sort the `df` first (a rather costly operation).
- For the groups, get [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html), i.e. the index for the max value for each group. Chain [`Series.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.0rc1/api/generated/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html) to use the result to select from `df_purchase` with [`df.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html).

```
df_purchase['order_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_purchase['order_date'])
res = df_purchase.iloc[df_purchase.groupby('item_code')\
                  ['order_date'].idxmax().to_numpy()].reset_index(drop=True)

print(res)

  order_date order_id item_code  price
0 2022-09-30      004     12-05     17
1 2022-05-03      002     13-05     21
```

Note that this will get you `13-05` before `12-05`. So, if you are set on the particular order in `res`, you will still need to sort, of course.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please be sure to answer the question. Provide details and share your research!